# Javascript Array and Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two arrays of objects.Where each object has different properties, Like this

```
    let array1=[
    {id:121122,name:"Matt Jeff"},
    {id:121123,name:"Philip Jeff"}, 
    {id:121124,name:"Paul Jeff"}]
    
    let array2=[
    {owner_id:121122,id:1211443,value:18},
    {owner_id:121127,id:1211428,value:22}]
```

How can I check if the owner_id in the array2 is equal to the id in array1 then return the new array like this

```
let newArray=[
{owner_id:121122,id:1211443,value:18}
]
```

Where the owner_id in array2 is equal to the id in array1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you need, you could do like this:

```js
let array1 = [{
    id: 121122,
    name: "Matt Jeff"
  }, {
    id: 121123,
    name: "Philip Jeff"
  }, {
    id: 121124,
    name: "Paul Jeff"
  }
]

let array2 = [{
    owner_id: 121122,
    id: 1211443,
    value: 18
  }, {
    owner_id: 121127,
    id: 1211428,
    value: 22
  }
]

const result = array2.filter(({ owner_id }) => array1.some(({ id }) => id === owner_id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with nested `for` like:

```js
let array1=[
    {id:121122,name:"Matt Jeff"},
    {id:121123,name:"Philip Jeff"}, 
    {id:121124,name:"Paul Jeff"}]
    
    let array2=[
    {owner_id:121122,id:1211443,value:18},
    {owner_id:121127,id:1211428,value:22}];
    
let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array1[i].id === array2[j].owner_id) {
         result.push(array2[j]);
      }
   }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

### EFFICIENT WAY: Using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`O(m)` - Iterating on array1 and Storing the id in `Set`

`O(n)` - Iterating on the array2 and filtering the result which include `O(1)` to search in `Set`;

```js
let array1 = [
  { id: 121122, name: "Matt Jeff" },
  { id: 121123, name: "Philip Jeff" },
  { id: 121124, name: "Paul Jeff" },
];

let array2 = [
  { owner_id: 121122, id: 1211443, value: 18 },
  { owner_id: 121127, id: 1211428, value: 22 },
];

const dict = new Set();
array1.forEach((o) => dict.add(o.id));

const result = array2.filter((o) => dict.has(o.owner_id));

console.log(result);
```